# Cannot implement INDIRECT() within an array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet named *Finder* at which I created a tool to search in other sheets (named #1, #2, etc). The problem I encountered with is that I can't use the INDIRECT function in some cases as described below:

```
 { = IF(Finder!$B$4 = 1,
        INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "'!$A$2:$A$100", "'!$B$2:$B$100")),
              SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$B$2:$B$100)),
                       "",
                       ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1),
                    INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
              1),
        IF(Finder!$B$4 = 2,
           INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!" & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "$A$2:$A$100", "$B$2:$B$100")),
                 SMALL(IF(Finder!$F$4 = '#1'!$B$2:$B$100,
                          ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1,
                          ""),
                       INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
                 1),... }
```

Conceptual form:

```
 { = IF(Finder!$B$4 = 1,
        INDEX(using INDIRECT to address a range in another sheet successfully,
              SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(cannot use INDIRECT here!)),
                       "",
                       Desired value),
                    Desired item),
              1),
        IF(Finder!$B$4 = 2,
           INDEX(using INDIRECT to address a range in another sheet successfully,
                 SMALL(IF(cannot use INDIRECT here!,
                          Desired value,
                          ""),
                       Desired item),
                 1),... }
```

I need to address a range in another sheets like below:

```
SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$B$2:$B$100)),...

SMALL(IF(Finder!$F$4 = '#1'!$B$2:$B$100,...
```

it's OK, but I can't use INDIRECT to make the formula dynamic:

```
SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Finder!$F$4, INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))),...

SMALL(IF(Finder!$F$4 = INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"),...
```

Thanks in advance

---

***UPDATE:***

[image: Finder Sheet]

The Finder tool contains many cells. The picture shows why I need to obtain a sheet name using `ROW()` function.

***UPDATE 2:***

[image: #1 Sheet]

The combobox in the Finder sheet has four items and uses $B$4 cell:

  1- Approximate Search

  2- Exact Search

  3- Full Index

  4- Specific Category

Here is the full code of the formula:

```
= IF(ISERROR(IF(Finder!$B$4 = 1,
                INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "'!$A$2:$A$100", "'!$B$2:$B$100")),
                      SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$B$2:$B$100)),
                               "",
                               ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1),
                            INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
                      1),
                IF(Finder!$B$4 = 2,
                   INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!" & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "$A$2:$A$100", "$B$2:$B$100")),
                         SMALL(IF(Finder!$F$4 = '#1'!$B$2:$B$100,
                                  ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1,
                                  ""),
                               INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
                         1),
                   IF(Finder!$B$4 = 3,
                      IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0,
                         20 * (ROW() - 6) + COLUMN() / 3,
                         INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INT(COLUMN() / 3) + 1, 2, 1, , "#" & (ROW() - 5)))),
                      INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!" & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "$A$2:$A$100", "$B$2:$B$100")),
                            SMALL(IF(Finder!$F$4 = '#1'!$I$2:$I$100,
                                     ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1,
                                     IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Finder!$F$4 & ",", '#1'!$I$2:$I$100)),
                                        IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("," & Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$I$2:$I$100)),
                                           IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(", " & Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$I$2:$I$100)),
                                              "",
                                              ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1),
                                           ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1),
                                        ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1)),
                                  INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
                            1))))),
     " ",
     IF(Finder!$B$4 = 1,
        INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "'!$A$2:$A$100", "'!$B$2:$B$100")),
              SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$B$2:$B$100)),
                       "",
                       ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1),
                    INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
              1),
        IF(Finder!$B$4 = 2,
           INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!" & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "$A$2:$A$100", "$B$2:$B$100")),
                 SMALL(IF(Finder!$F$4 = '#1'!$B$2:$B$100,
                          ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1,
                          ""),
                       INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
                 1),
           IF(Finder!$B$4 = 3,
              IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0,
                 20 * (ROW() - 6) + COLUMN() / 3,
                 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INT(COLUMN() / 3) + 1, 2, 1, , "#" & (ROW() - 5)))),
              INDEX(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!" & IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 3) = 0, "$A$2:$A$100", "$B$2:$B$100")),
                    SMALL(IF(Finder!$F$4 = '#1'!$I$2:$I$100,
                             ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1,
                             IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Finder!$F$4 & ",", '#1'!$I$2:$I$100)),
                                IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("," & Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$I$2:$I$100)),
                                   IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(", " & Finder!$F$4, '#1'!$I$2:$I$100)),
                                      "",
                                      ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1),
                                   ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1),
                                ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100")) - MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("'#" & (ROW() - 5) & "'!$B$2:$B$100"))) + 1)),
                          INT(COLUMN() / 3)),
                    1)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by use of `ROW` and `COLUMN` functions. These functions return "arrays" even when only a single value, e.g. {1} rather than 1. In some contexts that's not an issue but in other cases (like here), excel has a problem converting {1} to 1 and the formulas don't work.

One possible solution is to enclose all `ROW` and `COLUMN` functions in a function like `MAX` or `SUM` which will convert for you, e.g. instead of

`ROW() - 5`

use

`SUM(ROW()) - 5`

but a better way (and the one I recommend) is to use `ROWS` or `COLUMNS` functions (with **"S"** on the end), so if first formula is in `Z6` use

`ROWS($Z$6:Z6)` or `COLUMNS($Z$6:Z6)`

those will both give you a value of 1 in Z6 itself but as you copy down or across they will increment by 1 each time (and they don't suffer the same drawback as `ROW` and `COLUMN`). This is a better solution anyway as it does away with your -5s and it's less susceptible to error should you delete or add rows or columns

Comment: Thanks @barry houndini. I added a picture to demonstrate why I need to use `ROW()` function to address a sheet name. In fact, I'm trying to make a vocabulary bank. So I placed many words in #1, #2, ... sheets. In these sheets, each word has a unique number and placed in column A and the words are in the second column. (column B) I tried to solve the problem using `SUM()` and `MAX()`, but it didn't solve it.

Comment: I updated the question again and added the full code. Please take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: OK, I understood why you were using ROW but it causes a problem as I said....but don't you have the sheet numbers listed in **column B**, why can't you use those - that would be simpler than ROW, ROWS or any other way?

Comment: I really don't have any idea about using column B. The formula is used in C6, D6, F6, G6, ..., C7, D7, F7, G7 and so on. How can I obtain the current row?!

Comment: Your formula is using ROW()-5 in row 6, so that gives you 1....but in B6 you already have 1, so rather than using ROW()-5 (which is causing you problems anyway), why not just refer to B6? In the rest of column B you appear to have 2,3,4 etc. so that will work for every row

Comment: Sorry! I haven't understood you yet! The formula is supposed to remain constant in all cells. How can I use the data in column B explicitly?

Comment: You should be able to replace all instances of **(ROW()-5)** with **$B6**

Comment: I used the formula in row 6, 7, 8, ... 100. The $B6 gets 6 all the time and consequently I have to update the formula for each row which will cause a pain. I need a dynamic formula to remain unchanged to be applied to whole cells.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42276/discussion-between-mimi-and-barry-houdini)

Comment: Thanks again Barry! I wrote a true formula for the first cell with updatable row and column. So when I populate it to other cells, it's updated automatically.