# Reference alternating cells in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an excel document and need to reference alternating cells in the same row. Usually, we do `A1:A3`, and this covers A1, A2, A3. I am trying to make it reference A1, A3, A5 in the same way. I have tried `=INDIRECT("E"&ROW(0:2)*2+1)`, but this gives an array of #VALUE?. Is there another way. The reference must be usable by functions such as AVERAGE and LINEST.

I tried `=INDIRECT("E"&ROW(0:2)*2+1)` and expected it to give an array of A1, A3, A5.

Comment: My personal rule: if you find yourself contemplating using `INDIRECT` ... don't. An exception is using it to reference cells on a different worksheet. `=LET(c,A1:A5,INDEX(c,SEQUENCE(INT((ROWS(c)+1)/2),,,2)))` will do the job.

Comment: Find an explanation here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309517/cannot-implement-indirect-within-an-array-formula), any perhaps can adapt the answers

Comment: There is no row 0 and INDIRECT won't work like that. You could use `INDEX(E:E,ROW(A1:A3)*2-1)` which will work with `LINEST` (there is no SUMMARY function in Excel so I'm not sure what you meant by that?)

Comment: Use ODD() to check if the row() is odd or even()  and then if().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SEQUENCE()` function.

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(3,,,2),LAMBDA(x,INDIRECT("A"&x)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with `INDIRECT`, that how it is related to arrays as parameters, and `array formulas`
Founding these in SO

[Using INDIRECT with an Array Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824199/using-indirect-with-an-array-input)

[Cannot implement INDIRECT() within an array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309517/cannot-implement-indirect-within-an-array-formula)

and this works (really not quite understand how)

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW(1:3)*2-1),"<>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this could be one method:

[image]